# Python's Namespace Packages are not Visible in Local Development Project

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-packaging, namespace-package

I'm trying to split a big (almost monolithic) Python project into multiple pieces by utilizing Pythons [*namespace packages*](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/). Therefore I extracted a parser for `*.rules` files into a *namespace package*. Python calls this a *distribution*.

I followed that guide and as far as I can tell it partially works, but ...

**In short:** In the main project, the namespaces of separately distributed namespace packages are not visible, because the package search finds local packages first and does not merge with the system packages from `site-packages`.

## Project Structure

Here is a part of my directory / package and module structure.

**Main project:**

```
pyIPCMI/                  # Git repository root
  pyIPCMI/
    __init__.py
    Common/
      __init__.py
      File1.py
    Compiler/
      __init__.py
      Vendor1.py
      Vendor2.py
  setup.py
```

**Distribution for rules parser**

```
pyIPCMI.Parser.Rules/     # Git repository root
  pyIPCMI/
    Parser/
      Rules/
        __init__.py
        Parser.py
  setup.py
```

## Package Descriptions (setuptools)

**The main project is packaged like this:**

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
  name="pyIPCMI",
  version="1.1.5",
  author="Paebbels",
  author_email="abc@xyz.de",
  description="",
  long_description="",
  url="https://github.com/Paebbels/pyIPCMI",

  packages=setuptools.find_packages(),

  classifiers=["License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License"],
  python_requires='>=3.5',
  install_requires=[],
)
```

**The embedded namespace is packaged like this:**

```
import setuptools

namespace =   ["pyIPCMI", "Parser", "Rules"]

setuptools.setup(
  name=".".join(namespace),
  version="1.1.4",
  author="Paebbels",
  author_email="abc@xyz.de",
  description="",
  long_description="",
  url="https://github.com/Paebbels/pyIPCMI.Parser.Rules",

  packages=setuptools.find_namespace_packages(
    include=[".".join(namespace), ".".join(namespace) + ".*"]
  ),
  namespace_packages=namespace[0:1],

  classifiers=["License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License"],
  python_requires='>=3.5',
  install_requires=[],
)
```

All distributions have been:

- packaged with `setuptools` using Travis-CI
- deployed to PyPI, and then
- installed on the local machine using `pip`.

## Namespace Structure at PyPI

```
pyIPCMI
pyIPCMI.Parser.Files
pyIPCMI.Parser.Rules
pyIPCMI.Toolchains
pyIPCMI.Toolchains.Vendor1
pyIPCMI.Toolchains.Vendor2
```

## Problem Description

When developing in the main project with e.g. PyCharm, the locally found namespaces are preferred over packages from `site-packages`. Moreover, these namespace don't get merged.
Because the main project has the same root namespace `pyIPCMI`, search continues in the local development project but does not search in `site-packages`.

Any idea how to be able to develop the main project?

---

*Please advise what information is needed to solve this question. I tried to write down all information I have so far. But this question may need improvement to get a solution.*

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question?

Comment: I couldn't investigate it further in the last months. I wanted to strip down my problem to a very simple package / sub-package setup with a few imports and print statements in multiple files/modules for further testing and/or reporting.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem last week and found the solution. As first example,
let me give you my initial (non-working) layout.

### Directory Structure 1 (plugins not yet extracted)

```
project-dir
  +-- pyproject.toml/setup.py
  +-- myproject
        +-- __init__.py
        +-- app.py
        +-- plugins
              +-- __init__.py
              +-- plugin1
                    +-- __init__.py
                    +-- plugmodule.py
              +-- plugin2
                    +-- __init__.py
                    +-- plugmodule.py
```

The application already had code to find plugin modules based on this
structure. When writing this, my initial understanding was that I could provide
additional plugins by creating Python-packages with the following structure:

```
plugin-package-dir
  +-- pyproject.toml/setup.py
  +-- myproject
        +-- plugins
              +-- plugin3
                    +-- __init__.py
                    +-- plugmodule.py
```

As mentioned in the official docs, the namespace packages don't contain
`__init__.py` files here.

**But this did not work**

### Solution

In order to make this work, I needed to extract the "plugins" package
completely from the main project subtree by making this a pure namespace
packages as well. This new package then needs to be manually added to your `setup.py`/`pyproject.toml` as it is not recognized by default package discovery.

I ended up with the following structure:

```
project-dir
  +-- pyproject.toml/setup.py
  +-- myproject
        +-- __init__.py
        +-- app.py
  +-- myproject_plugins
        +-- plugins
              +-- plugin1
                    +-- __init__.py  # <-- not strictly needed? (see note)
                    +-- plugmodule.py
              +-- plugin2
                    +-- __init__.py  # <-- not strictly needed? (see note)
                    +-- plugmodule.py
```

And then for the plugin packages I have this:

```
plugin-package-dir
  +-- pyproject.toml/setup.py
  +-- myproject_plugins
        +-- plugins
              +-- plugin3
                    +-- plugmodule.py
              +-- plugin4
                    +-- plugmodule.py
```

**NOTE**: The `__init__.py` files exist in the main project plugins because of
the way I load plugins. In order to iterate over the namespace I import it
during plugin discovery. I could instead catch the `ImportError` and report
that no plugin was found at all.

I have not investigated 100% if I can remove the `__init__.py` and catch the
import error. I have lost already too much time on this and don't want to break
something that's working right now ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the namespace packages have to be really empty, and this in all installed projects.

Apparently your `pyIPCMI` project has a top level *non-namespace-package* `pyIPCMI`, i.e. you have a `pyIPCMI/__init__.py` file. So I don't think you can have a `pyIPCMI` namespace package in other projects. I would try removing this `pyIPCMI/__init__.py` file (and make it a namespace package as well) if you want `pyIPCMI` to be a namespace package in the other projects.